# What are the consequences of deleting a branch that's not fully merged?

Tags: git

If you try to delete a branch that has commits that can't be reached by another branch (local or upstream), then you get this of course:

```
git branch -d <branch>
error: The branch <branch> is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D <branch>'.
```

But what if I don't care about the commits made specifically on that branch? If I delete the branch anyway, what happens to them, and what happens to the commits on other branches?

Comment: Commits will stay for some time, long enough for you to find them. When you delete a ref including a branch, only the ref and its reflog are gone, the commits are still there. They can usually be found by `git reflog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the branch, the commits will disappear with the branch. They will not be accessible through any other branch.

Think of it as making a photo-copy of a document, then making changes to the photo-copy with a highlighter. If you choose to shred the photo-copy before transferring your edits to the original copy, then your edits disappear and there are no consequences propagated anywhere else.

Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: While in a sense, the commits "disappear", they are easily recoverable within a short time after deleting the branch until they are garbage collected.

Comment: Sure, the point I was speaking to was the fact that there are no consequences other than on the branch being deleted.

Answer (score 4):

There are no consequences, other than that the branch gets deleted and any commits that were only reachable via that branch will be deleted as well. Git is just making sure that you *really* want to destroy your work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the commits do not disappear immediately. Only the branch is deleted. This makes it more difficult to find the commits which were on the deleted branch but not on any other branch. You can find them with `git reflog`.

If you want to remove the commits entirely in order to free up disk space, then you can run `git gc`. This command is run periodically when you run other commands, so there is not usually a reason to run it manually. Your git settings will specify how old a commit or other object must be before it is eligible for garbage collection.